# How to return the lines with the max length in a dataset

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have updated the code with the correct one , it's one possible solution

/******************************************/

I have a dataset of tuples contain two values(`string line ,integer length_of_line` ) and I am trying to return the tuples with the max `length_of_line`

I tried using the `.maxBy()` function but the output is only one tuple.

```java
public class PalindromeTaskImpl implements PalindromeTask {

    @Override
    public Set<String> solve(String inputFile) throws Exception {

        class PalindromeChecker implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(String str, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {
                String whatever = new String(str);
                str = str.replace(" ","");
                int startIndex = 0;
                int endIndex = str.length() - 1;

                while (startIndex < endIndex) {
                    char getAtl = str.charAt(startIndex);
                    char getAth = str.charAt(endIndex);
                    if (getAtl != getAth) {
                        out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(str, 0));
                        return;
                    }
                    startIndex++;
                    endIndex--;
                }
                out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(whatever, str.length()));
            }
        }

        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        //DataSet<String> inputData = env.readTextFile(inputFile);

        DataSet<String> inputData = env.fromElements(
                "abc cba 33\n" +
                        " abc abc cba cba \n" +
                        "4 qwer fg gf rewq 4\n" +
                        "a qder fg gf redq a\n" +
                        "a qder fg abc cba gf redq a\n" +
                        "abcde abcde edcba edcba 33  "
        );

        DataSet<String> oneLine =inputData.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String> () {

            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<String> oneLine) {
                for (String token : value.split("\n")) {
                    oneLine.collect(token);
                }
            }
        });

        DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> PalindromeCheckerResults =
                oneLine.flatMap(new PalindromeChecker());

        DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> palindromeSentence = PalindromeCheckerResults.maxBy(1);
        int maxVal = palindromeSentence.collect().get(0).f1;

        DataSet<String> result =
                PalindromeCheckerResults.filter(new FilterFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(Tuple2<String, Integer> stringIntegerTuple2) throws Exception {
                        return stringIntegerTuple2.f1 == maxVal;
                    }
                })

                        .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String,Integer>, String>() {
                            public void flatMap(Tuple2<String,Integer> value, Collector<String> result) {
                                {result.collect(value.f0);
                                }
                            }
                        });

        Set<String> finalSetResult = null;
        try {
            finalSetResult = new HashSet<String>(result.collect());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return finalSetResult;
    }


}
```

The function palindrome above check if the line is palindrome then return the line with its length if it's palindrome or 0 if it's not. The output is `tuple2 (string,integer)`.
When I run it with `sampleData.flatMap(new PalindromeCheck()).maxBy(1);` the code above the output is :

(a qder fg gf redq a,19)

while the expected result should be :

(4 qwer fg gf rewq 4,19)

(a qder fg gf redq a,19)

Comment: Shouldn't the max be `abcde abcde edcba edcba 33`? And that is only one result

Comment: How are you getting the count of the length of lines anyway? The default LineSplitter doesn't do that

Comment: i am sorry , my mistake i have added the wrong code , it was misleading!

Comment: `maxBy` returns a single value per group or a single value of all tuples. If you want all tuples for the max value, you have to compute the max value first and then filter on this value.

Comment: i know it's so similar to the sql concept but i don't know how to do it , i am new to Java  and Flink:D

Comment: what do you mean by you don't know how? You basically have two Flink jobs. The first is similar to what you did, you compute the maximum of the second column. And then in a second job, you get all tuples that have the maximum length. In SQL this would be what you did with a sub-SELECT

Comment: You shouldn't be using FlatMap for this. You're outputting one tuple per input string, so just use Map Function

Comment: If you'd rather use SQL than Java, that's an option -- Flink supports SQL.